# How to optimally store the viewing time of an episode in the database?

Tags: mysql, laravel

How to optimally store the viewing time of an episode in the database? What I have done now is that as soon as the user starts an episode 1- At first, it is checked whether there is a user observation record in the table or not. 2- If there is, the time column will be updated with Ajax every second 3- If it does not exist, a record will be recorded and the viewing time will be recorded again in the table Note: This system is currently working well, but my question is, if, for example, a thousand people are watching the episodes at the same time, will the database not face a serious problem? Every second, four queries are sent by one person, and if a thousand people see it, this number reaches four thousand queries per second, what is the best solution? Does this system not cause failure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A consideration is how accurate you want the viewing time to be.

You could for instance, write the viewing time to the session (only) and then persist it to the database every minute, or when the viewer navigates to a new page.

But, every second seems an unrealistic expectation since you have per second requests to your server coming in from every viewer.

So, consider what is reasonable.  If it is just for your own stats then maybe 10 second increments is enough.  If it is so that the user can leave and return to the exact second they left then again, possible, but probably unreasonable.  I don't expect this to happen with youtube or netflix - there is normally some amount of overlap, which actually helps me remember where I got to.

Comment: The problem here is that if a video is 75 seconds (for example) the last five seconds will not be recorded.
Because the query is executed every ten seconds

Comment: You can send a separate event when the video ends